# Visualizations of the (potential) irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$

Tags: euclidean-geometry, irrational-numbers, visualization

The following statement is equivalent to Euclid's statement that [$\sqrt{2}$ is irrational](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookX/propX21.html) but has a rather different flavour.

Consider the straight line through two points $0$ and $1$ with the natural numbers $[\mathbb{N}]$ constructed as points

$[n] = 1 + 1 + \dots + 1$ ($n$-times):

[image]

Consider the point $1'$ constructed like this:

[image]

Define $[\mathbb{N}]'$ as the set of points constructed as

$[n]' = 1' + 1' + \dots + 1'$ ($n$-times):

[image]

Then the statement goes:

> For all $n,m$: If $[n] = [m]'$ then $m = n = 0$.

This means, the sets $[\mathbb{N}]$ and $[\mathbb{N}]'$ have only the point $0$ in common. For no $n,m \neq 0$ do the points $[n]$ and $[m]'$ happen to coincide.

I wonder if this visual and conceptual perspective on the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$ has been taken and discussed before, or if it's even a standard perspective - and if not so: if it's an enlightening perspective?

---

**Added:** Another - and more straight forward - way to state the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$ geometrically is by stating that there are no $n,m \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that the point $n/m$ constructed this way:

[image]

coincides with the point $1' = \sqrt{2}$:

[image]

Note that this statement is much harder to draw accurately and to catch and believe visually.

Note further, that this picture does not imply a visual proof of the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$, neither.

---

**Added:** Another - even simpler but less straight forward - way to state the same geometrically is by this construction over two Gaussian integers $n = p + q\ i$, $m = r + s\ i$, which gives the rational point $x(n,m) = p - q\frac{p-r}{q-s}$:

[image]

The statement is: For no two Gaussian integers $n = p + q\ i$, $m= r + s\ i$ does $x(n,m)$ coincide with $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: +1) In essence it is [Dedekind's notion of cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_cut): if you consider the horizontal line with **only** rational numbers and you "project the diagonal of the unit square on it, the compass will not "cut" the line, because there is no intersection (rational) point.

Answer (score 4):

The first picture proves the constructibility of $\sqrt2$.

The second illustrates the concept of irrationality.

There is nothing here about the irrationality of $\sqrt2$.

Comment: I admit that! A proof that the tick marks never coincide doesn't immediately follow from the construction. But it's a way to define and visualize irrationality: A number $\alpha$ is irrational when $m\alpha, m \in \mathbb{Z}$ only coincides with $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ when $m = n = 0$ (see Ennar's answer).

Comment: I admit there is no visible link between the two constructions, but on the other side: there *is* one, it's only not visible immediately.

Comment: You are perfectly right: It's just a visualization of irrationality (as a concept), and certainly no "visual proof" of the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$. Thank you for making this clear. (But I won't change the title of my question, OK?)

Comment: I don't think the visualization was intended as any sort of proof, just a geometric restatement of the definition of irrationality. IMO, such visualization could be very beneficial for educational purposes for the students first encountering irrational numbers compared to the dull "decimal representation of irrational number is infinite and non-periodic".

Comment: @Ennar: Thank you for your comment. That's exactly how I intended my question. (I should have mentioned it). What you say about the dull "decimal representations of irrational number are infinite and non-periodic" perfectly hits the point.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: What I wanted to say: Stating that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational is equivalent with stating, that no two points $n,m' \neq 0$ coincide when constructing $1'$ like above.

Comment: Yves, I agree that this is not about $\sqrt 2$, but irrational numbers in general. However, $\sqrt 2$ is a concrete example and if one did couple of them (maybe some other square roots, something constructible, anyway), one could then say that numbers with such property are called irrational. This is quite close to the idea of incommensurability.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: For the record: As depicted the first two pictures actually "imply" the third. But since the pictures are finite, it's not implied that the non-matching of the tick marks will continue forever - this cannot be seen. And also not the reason *why* this should be so.

Comment: @Ennar: Is it possible to contact you by email?

Comment: @Hans, sure, I've included that info on my SE profile.

Answer (score 2):

It is not just $\sqrt 2$, you can actually characterize all irrational numbers in such a way.

So, let $\alpha\in\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ and consider set $\{k\alpha\,\mid\, k\in\mathbb Z\}$. That set will contain non-zero integers if and only if $\alpha\in\mathbb Q$. This is essentially what you wrote. However, this is nothing new from the usual definition of (ir)rational number.

We can make things more interesting, though, by considering not $\{k\alpha\,\mid\, k\in\mathbb Z\}$ on a line, but on a circle instead (by wrapping the real line on a circle). Formally, for a non-zero real $\alpha$ consider the set of integer multiples of $\alpha$ on a circle  $\{k\alpha + \mathbb Z\,\mid\, k\in\mathbb Z\}\subseteq \mathbb R/\mathbb Z \cong \mathbb S^1.$

One interesting thing to note is that for irrational $\alpha$, $k\alpha + \mathbb Z,\ k\in\mathbb Z$, are all distinct. Moreover, the following is true:

> The set of integer multiples of non-zero real $\{k\alpha + \mathbb Z\,\mid\, k\in\mathbb Z\}$ is finite if and only if $\alpha\in\mathbb Q.$ Otherwise, it is **dense** in $\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Z\cong \mathbb S^1.$

There is an elementary argument as to why this is true that you can find [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/127728/45668).

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer to your question - but perhaps what you are looking for.

[image]

> Assuming $a^2=2b^2$, with positive integers $a$ and $b$, one can
>   easily establish that also $(2b−a)^2=2(a−b)^2$. The impossibility of
>   the former lies in the fact that $a>2b−a$ (which shows that we are
>   just at the beginning of an infinite descent.) This is one of the
>   proofs of the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$.

https://www.cut-the-knot.org/proofs/GraphicalSqRoots.shtml

Comment: To be a "proof without words" this would require that you can literally "see" that  $(2b-a)^2 = 2(a-b)^2$ which is the content of the [carpets theorem](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/CarpetsInSquare.shtml). But I found this quite hard - and the proof is involved.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! But to be honest: It's [Tom Apostol's proof](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/proofs/sq_root.shtml#proof7) that is really a perfect "proof without words" - without much explanation you immeadiately *see*, why infinite descent would be possible

Comment: @HansStricker I agree. That is in fact the proof I vaguely remembered when I searched for the one I eventually posted. You should provide another answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Following Ethan's advice I want to draw your attention to [Apostol's proof of the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$](http://hipatia.dma.ulpgc.es/profesores/personal/aph/ficheros/resolver/ficheros/crp/2root_2000.pdf) which is as visual as a proof can be (in my opinion): One can literally *see* at a glance that it proves what it's supposed to prove: the impossibility of a isosceles triangle with integer side length (by infinite descent):

[image]

Note that it's not a proof completely without words. It helps a lot to read the comments of the author:

> Each line segment in the diagram has integer length, and the three
>   segments with double tick marks have equal lengths. (Two of them are
>   tangents to the circle from the same point.) Therefore the smaller
>   isosceles right triangle with hypotenuse on the horizontal base also
>   has integer sides.

But through own thinking one could come up with this by oneself (having in mind what's to be proved).